# Error in tutorial 10---rosmake beginner_tutorials

Tags: rosmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I followed all the steps in tutorials till tutorial 10 and did not have even one error.
But in tutorial 10 during the instruction----there are lot of errors. I understood that it is cyclic dependency errors and it shows that

roscpp depends on itself

Samlpe Output

```
sai@sai-desktop:~$ rosmake beginner_tutorials 
-------
  File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/rosmake/engine.py", line 314, in build_or_recurse
    self.build_or_recurse(d)
  File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/rosmake/engine.py", line 314, in build_or_recurse
    self.build_or_recurse(d)
  File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/rosmake/engine.py", line 314, in build_or_recurse
    self.build_or_recurse(d)
  File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/rosmake/engine.py", line 313, in build_or_recurse
    for d in self.dependency_tracker.get_deps_1(p):
  File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/rosmake/parallel_build.py", line 97, in get_deps_1
    if not package in self.deps_1:
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in cmp
```

Please help..

Thanks,
Sai

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40467/error-in-tutorial-10---rosmake-beginner_tutorials/) by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1935 on 2012-08-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you remove the erroneous depends tag you added here:

http://answers.ros.org/question/40456/cannot-find-rosh/

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-08-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3